# MySQL Match Against Exact Phrase end to end

Tags: mysql, match

```
select text1,text2 from text where match(text1) against('"i love to"' in boolean mode)
```

This will column match:

"i love to"

"i love to eat"

"i love to read"

Is it possible to match exactly **"i love to"** and not the rest?

Comment: If you want exactly "I love to", use LIKE "I love to" instead of MATCH AGAINST

Comment: @ôkio :-) I even don't see any reason to use `LIKE` just `WHERE text1 = "i love to"`  . I thought OP needs to get all values ended by this string *i love to* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5744/6. But finally I see it was just about exact matching.